# How to find word position in sentence with string, array at php.

Tags: php, string

please help me.
so how to find word position in sentece.
ex : one two five six seven two. 
finding : **two**. 
answer : 2 and 6

Comment: split your input string according to the space and get the array index if the corresponding value is `two`

Comment: http://php.net/strpos

Comment: Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```
$needle = 'two';
$positions = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        str_word_count($sentence, 1),
        function ($value) use ($needle) {
            return $value == $needle;
        }
    )
);
```

**EDIT**

If you really need the offset of the first word to be 1 rather than 0, then modify the above so:

```
$positions = array_map(
    function($position) {
        return ++$position;
    },
    array_keys(
        array_filter(
            str_word_count($sentence, 1),
            function ($value) use ($needle) {
                return $value == $needle;
            }
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks before
Ex : apple orange strawberry apple
find position : apple 
answer : position in 1 & 4

like that..
thank you sir